# sequelize-cli cannot run migration because there is no proper Dialect supplied in migration-config.js

Tags: sequelize.js

sequelize-cli cannot run migrations because: `Dialect needs to be explicity supplied as of v4.0.0`. sequelize-cli is trying to load the configuration from `config/migration-config.js` which is the file autogenerated by sequelize-cli init. Now, I have been serching for example of how to configurate this file but all the documentation I found is about a file config.json. so, wehere I can find documentation about the migration-cofig.js file?

**migration-config.js:**

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` });

const config = {};

config[process.env.NODE_ENV] = {
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: 3306,
  dialect: 'mysql',
}

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of the config.json file would be helpful to answer your question. It looks like it is not specified which dialect you are using. As an example, if you use mysql you have to specify in config.json file "dialect": "mysql". Make sure to pay attention which environment you are using "development", "test" or "production" and specify the dialect accordingly.

Comment: As I said, the problem is in the `migration-config.js` file. Sequelize does not care about the existence of a `config.json` file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).